# Is there any limit of characters in command line arguments in spark submit command?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I also want to know if there are any special characters which we can not use in arguments to the spark submit command?

I also want to know can we pass a whole nested Json String to the argument in spark submit command?

One additional question is how to run a spark program using a java code (from another program)?

So, do we have to run our other program on cluster (A linux machine with spark installed) to run my spark program?

I am too confused in this matter; please suggest.

Comment: Please ask two separate questions, not two in one.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question: *One additional question is how to run a spark program using a java code (from another program)?* 
In your java program if you have a Maven project, you can add a maven dependency.
Spark artifacts are hosted in Maven Central. You can add a Maven dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If not, you can choose to download the jar file and add it as an external library to your java code. 
After any of this options, you will be able to write java spark code in your java program.
You can find the dependency and the jar file here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/1.4.1
Yes, you need a machine with Spark to run your code. In order to run it you can make an executable jar out of your program and run it with:

```
$: spark/bin/spark-submit --class com.your.MainClass --master spark://your_master_node:7077 your_jar_file.jar
```

Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate your answer but this is what we do for writing a java program using spark but my question was how could I run a separate spark(with java) program from another java program?

I have posted it seperately here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582892/how-to-run-a-spark-program-on-cluster-from-within-a-separate-java-program